# How to make checkboxes rounded?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to make checkboxes with rounded corners using bootstrap or some css property?

Comment: Detailed CheckBox styling via advanced CSS3 is described in : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/887167/Toggle-Button-built-on-ASP-NET-CheckBox-and-HTML-C . Hope this will help. Regards,

Comment: just use a radio button sideshow bob.

Answer (score 84):

Just using css, however, you lose the checkbox tick.

```css
.checkbox-round {
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-round:checked {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" />
```

Comment: what about non-webkit browsers?

Comment: @SabaAhang Added `appearance: none;`

Answer (score 28):

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  
border-radius: 15px;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 12):

One of the Best And Easiest Method is to use CSS clip path property:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox" >Option</label>
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 45px;                         /* Set width */
  height: 45px;                        /* Set height */
  clip-path: circle(46% at 50% 50%);   /* Set the clip path of circle*/
}
```

if you still see some pointed corners, try reducing the first percentage values, (where I have used 46%), play with it a little bit and it will definitely work.

Answer (score 12):

Well, this is the simplest and optimal solution. You set `appearance` to `none` and then use `clip-path` when its checked.

```css
.rounded-checkbox {
  width:35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rounded-checkbox:checked {
  appearance: auto;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
 <input
        type="checkbox"
        class="rounded-checkbox"
        id="checkbox"
      /> <label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to do

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.round {
  position: relative;
}

.round label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.round label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="round">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you think it would be possible to have a clickable text label that would trigger the checkbox ?

Comment: This solution breaks tab selection, and is inaccessible to people who use screen readers.

Comment: Thanks. How to center the checkbox horizontally and vertically, please?

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep it simple for everyone, since I don't think the answers say this. Just adding:

```
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Will make the border-radius work on the checkbox.

Comment: This is actually the best answer

Comment: You forgot to mention that this will also kill 'checked' state visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can change the shape of the check box using the bootstrap class `.rounded-circle`

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox rounded-circle" />
```

Comment: worked for me, in Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

- in css you may play with height, width, border-radius. basically height and width should be equal and border-radius should be half of them.
- if you are using bootstrap you can use this class and add it where your shape or in this case your checkbox class is: class="rounded-circle"
  look: [borders bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/borders/)

for example to make a checkbox rounded in bootstrap 5 (also working for v4):

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input
  class="form-check-input rounded-circle"
  type="checkbox"
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheck1">
  rounded checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.checkbox {
      clip-path: circle(46% at 50% 50%);
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
```

**No need to hide the default checkbox and create a custom just set the *clip-path* and you can easily achieve a *circular checkbox*.**

Answer (score -3):

I thing the best way to make a rounded corners is by using the `border-radius` property. [This site](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles) has a nice collection of checkboxes.
For example:

```
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
top: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
```

The last line`(border-radius: 10px)` will give you a checkbox with rounded corners.

Comment: Checkboxes aren't borders so using `border-radius` won't change anything,  and they generally can't even be styled to have a border in most browsers, unless you use the `outline` property instead, which isn't totally equivalent.

Comment: It's possible, look my answer

Comment: link is dead anyways

Comment: @skwisgaar maybe because this answer was added 3 years ago

Comment: actually 4. but it changes nothing - it's dead. alas.