# Circle checkbox in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, checkbox

I am currently learning reacj.js and I am making a Todo app using react.js. I need to make a checkbox alongside the task and when that checkbox is clicked the task should move to completed section. I made it possible but I need a circle checkbox. How can I make a circle checkbox ???

Here's my code :

Javascript :

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'


function Body() {
    const [toDos,setToDos] = useState([])
  const [toDo,setToDo] = useState('')
  const deleteTodo = idToDelete => setToDos(currentTodos => currentTodos.filter(toDo => toDo.id !== idToDelete))
    return (
        <div className="bodyoftodo"> 
            <div className="input">
        <input value={toDo} onChange={(e)=>setToDo(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="️ Add item..." />
        <i onClick={()=>setToDos([...toDos,{id:Date.now() ,text: toDo, status: false}])} className="fas fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
      <div className="todos">
        {toDos.map((obj)=>{
          return(
            <div className="todo">
              <div className="left">
                <input onChange={(e)=>{
                  console.log(e.target.checked);
                  console.log(obj);
                  setToDos(toDos.filter(obj2=>{
                    if(obj2.id===obj.id){
                      obj2.status=e.target.checked
                    }
                    return obj2
                  }))
                }} value={obj.status} type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
                <p className='todoName' >{obj.text}</p>
              </div>
              
              <div className="right">
                <i onClick ={() => deleteTodo(obj.id)} className="fas fa-trash"></i>
              </div>
            </div>)
        }) }
        
        
        {
          toDos.map((obj)=>{
            if(obj.status){
              return(<h1 className="finished" >{obj.text}</h1>)
            }
            return null
          })
        }
        
        
        
      </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Body
```

CSS :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  font-family: "Segoe","Segoe UI","Arial","sans-serif";
}

.body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  
  
}

.app {
  position: absolute;
  
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
}

.app {
  text-align: center;
  
}

.app h1,
h2 {
  color: white;
}

.app .input {
  display: contents;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
 
}

.app .input {
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  width: 80em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
 
  

 
}

.app .input input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.6em;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  
}

.app i {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.app .todos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.app .todos .todo {
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  width: 80em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.app .todos .todo .left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.app .todos .todo .left  {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}
.mainHeading{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
.subHeading{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.finished{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type="text"]{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size:15px;
}
.todoName {
  margin-left: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.navbar{
  height: 48px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 96, 172);
  width: 85.4em;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  margin-right: 0em;
  
}
.bodyoftodo{
  position: fixed;
}
.titletodo{
  font-weight: 600;
    font-family: SegoeUI-SemiBold-final,Segoe UI Semibold,SegoeUI-Regular-final,Segoe UI,"Segoe UI Web (West European)",Segoe,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
  }
.linktitle{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: white;
}
.linktitle:hover {
  color:white;
}
.input{
  margin-left: 2.5em;
}
```

Comment: It has been answered here:
[How to make checkbox rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617200/how-to-make-checkboxes-rounded/41941208)

Comment: @IshanBassi But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Although a circle `checkbox` is like a `radio button` and maybe it makes a misunderstanding for user, by the way here is what you want.

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;
const Test = () => {
    const [toDos, setToDos] = useState([])
    const [toDo, setToDo] = useState('')
    const deleteTodo = idToDelete => setToDos(currentTodos => currentTodos.filter(toDo => toDo.id !== idToDelete))
    return ( <div className="bodyoftodo">
        <div className="input">
        <input value= {toDo}
        onChange= {
          (e) => setToDo(e.target.value)
        }
        type = "text"
        placeholder = "️ Add item..." / >
        <i onClick = {() => setToDos([...toDos, {
            id: Date.now(),
            text: toDo,
            status: false
          }])
        }
        className = "fas fa-plus"> add </i> </div>         <div className = "todos" > {
          toDos.map((obj) => {
              return ( <div className ="todo">
                <div className="left">
                <label class="container">
                <input onChange = {
                  (e) => {
                    console.log(e.target.checked);
                    console.log(obj);
                    setToDos(toDos.filter(obj2 =>{
                      if (obj2.id === obj.id) {
                      obj2.status=e.target.checked
                      }
                      return obj2
                    }))
                  }
                }
                value = {
                  obj.status
                }
                type = "checkbox"
                name = ""
                id = "" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <p className ='todoName'> {
                  obj.text
                } </p> </div>

                <div className = "right">
                <i onClick = {
                  () => deleteTodo(obj.id)
                }
                className = "fas fa-trash" > delete </i> 
                </div > 
                </div>)
              })
          }


          {
            toDos.map((obj) => {
                  if (obj.status) {
                    return ( < h1 className = "finished" > {
                        obj.text
                      } </h1>)
                    }
                    return null
                  })
              }


              </div>
              </div>
          )
        }
        ReactDOM.render( < Test / > ,
          document.getElementById('root')
        )
```

```css
/*****************Added By Ahmad*****************/
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.todo{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.todo .left{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.todo .right{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.todoName{
margin:0 10px;}

/*****************Added By Ahmad*****************/


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe", "Segoe UI", "Arial", "sans-serif";
}

.body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.app {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
}

.app {
  text-align: center;
}

.app h1,
h2 {
  color: white;
}

.app .input {
  display: contents;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.app .input {
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  width: 80em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.app .input input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.6em;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
}

.app i {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.app .todos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app .todos .todo {
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  width: 80em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.app .todos .todo .left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.app .todos .todo .left {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}

.mainHeading {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.subHeading {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.finished {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.todoName {
  /*margin-left: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 1em;*/
}

.navbar {
  height: 48px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 96, 172);
  width: 85.4em;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  margin-right: 0em;
}

.bodyoftodo {
  position: fixed;
}

.titletodo {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: SegoeUI-SemiBold-final, Segoe UI Semibold, SegoeUI-Regular-final, Segoe UI, "Segoe UI Web (West European)", Segoe, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.linktitle {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.linktitle:hover {
  color: white;
}

.input {
  margin-left: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```